# d3js code - how to add node names and property value on the edges

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, graph

I have a question about the below code...

Basically what Im trying to do is to add values on the edges between two nodes i.e. property values and also add some text inside the rectangles, can you pls suggest on what needs to be done here ?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@*" data-semver="3.2.2" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="d3@*" data-semver="3.2.2" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.2.2/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .node {
      stroke: #fff;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }

    .link {
      stroke: #999;
      stroke-opacity: .6;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
  var width = 800,
    height = 500,
    nodeWidth = 20,
    nodeHeight = 20;

  var fill = d3.scale.category10();

  var nodes = d3.range(100).map(function(i) {
  return {index: i};
  });

  var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-1000)
    .gravity(0.2)
    .linkDistance(30)                    
    .size([width, height])

  var first = 1;

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

  d3.json("data.json", function(error, graph) {
    var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(graph.links)
      .enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .style("stroke-width", 2 );

    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(graph.nodes)
      .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
        .attr("width", nodeWidth)
        .attr("height", nodeHeight)
        .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i & 3); })
        .style("stroke", function(d, i) { return d3.rgb(fill(i & 3)).darker(2); })
        .call(force.drag)
        .on("mousedown", function() { d3.event.stopPropagation(); });

    force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .on("tick", tick)
      .start();

    setTimeout(function() {
      first = 0;
      force.start();
    }, 6000);  

    function tick(e) {
      if(first) {
        var k = e.alpha;
      }
      else{
        var k = 10 * e.alpha;
      }
      graph.nodes.forEach(function(o, i) {
        o.y += (y(o.level) - o.y) * k; 
      });

      link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x + nodeWidth/2; })
          .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y + nodeHeight/2; })
          .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x + nodeWidth/2; })
          .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y + nodeHeight/2; });

      node.attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
          .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; });
    }
  });
  svg.style("opacity", 1e-6)
  .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .style("opacity", 1);

  d3.select("body")
    .on("mousedown", mousedown);

  var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(d3.range(5))
  .rangePoints([0, 100 * 5], 1);

  function mousedown() {
  nodes.forEach(function(o, i) {
    o.x += (Math.random() - .5) * 40;
    o.y += (Math.random() - .5) * 40;
  });
  force.resume();
  }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The datasource is as below

```
    {
  "nodes": [{
    "_id": 29,
    "gender": "female",
    "level": 2
  }, {
    "_id": 18,
    "gender": "male",
    "level": 3
  }, {
    "_id": 191,
    "gender": "male",
    "level": 1
  }, {
    "_id": 53,
    "gender": "male",
    "level": 2
  }, {
    "_id": 169,
    "gender": "female",
    "level": 1
  }, {
    "_id": 180,
    "gender": "male",
    "level": 1
  }, {
    "_id": 202,
    "gender": "female",
    "level": 1
  }, {
    "_id": 213,
    "gender": "male",
    "level": 2
  }, {
    "_id": 224,
    "gender": "female",
    "level": 2
  }, {
    "_id": 254,
    "gender": "male",
    "level": 3
  }, {
    "_id": 276,
    "gender": "male",
    "level": 3
  }, {
    "_id": 287,
    "gender": "female",
    "level": 3
  }, {
    "_id": 298,
    "gender": "male",
    "level": 2
  }, {
    "_id": 324,
    "gender": "male",
    "level": 3
  }, {
    "_id": 335,
    "gender": "female",
    "level": 3
  }, {
    "_id": 346,
    "gender": "male",
    "level": 3
  }, {
    "_id": 357,
    "gender": "female",
    "level": 4
  }, {
    "_id": 368,
    "gender": "female",
    "level": 4
  }, {
    "_id": 379,
    "gender": "female",
    "level": 3
  }, {
    "_id": 390,
    "gender": "female",
    "level": 0
  }, {
    "_id": 401,
    "gender": "male",
    "level": 0
  }, {
    "_id": 412,
    "gender": "female",
    "level": 0
  }, {
    "_id": 423,
    "gender": "male",
    "level": 0
  }, {
    "_id": 434,
    "gender": "male",
    "level": 0
  }, {
    "_id": 445,
    "gender": "female",
    "level": 0
  }, {
    "_id": 456,
    "gender": "female",
    "level": 0
  }, {
    "_id": 733,
    "gender": "female",
    "level": 2
  }, {
    "_id": 800,
    "gender": "male",
    "level": 2
  }, {
    "_id": 825,
    "gender": "female",
    "level": 2
  }],
  "links": [{
    "_id": 28,
    "source": 0,
    "target": 1
  }, {
    "_id": 52,
    "source": 1,
    "target": 3
  }, {
    "_id": 151,
    "source": 0,
    "target": 3
  }, {
    "_id": 168,
    "target": 0,
    "source": 4
  }, {
    "_id": 179,
    "source": 0,
    "target": 5
  }, {
    "_id": 190,
    "source": 2,
    "target": 3
  }, {
    "_id": 201,
    "target": 3,
    "source": 6
  }, {
    "_id": 212,
    "source": 2,
    "target": 7
  }, {
    "_id": 223,
    "source": 2,
    "target": 8
  }, {
    "_id": 249,
    "target": 2,
    "source": 6
  }, {
    "_id": 253,
    "source": 7,
    "target": 9
  }, {
    "_id": 275,
    "source": 8,
    "target": 10
  }, {
    "_id": 286,
    "target": 8,
    "source": 11
  }, {
    "_id": 297,
    "source": 8,
    "target": 12
  }, {
    "_id": 323,
    "source": 0,
    "target": 13
  }, {
    "_id": 334,
    "source": 0,
    "target": 14
  }, {
    "_id": 345,
    "target": 0,
    "source": 15
  }, {
    "_id": 356,
    "source": 13,
    "target": 16
  }, {
    "_id": 367,
    "source": 13,
    "target": 17
  }, {
    "_id": 378,
    "target": 13,
    "source": 18
  }, {
    "_id": 389,
    "target": 4,
    "source": 19
  }, {
    "_id": 400,
    "source": 4,
    "target": 20
  }, {
    "_id": 411,
    "source": 5,
    "target": 21
  }, {
    "_id": 422,
    "target": 5,
    "source": 22
  }, {
    "_id": 433,
    "target": 2,
    "source": 23
  }, {
    "_id": 444,
    "source": 2,
    "target": 24
  }, {
    "_id": 455,
    "source": 6,
    "target": 25
  }, {
    "_id": 466,
    "source": 4,
    "target": 5
  }, {
    "_id": 732,
    "target": 2,
    "source": 26
  }, {
    "_id": 799,
    "source": 5,
    "target": 27
  }, {
    "_id": 808,
    "target": 4,
    "source": 27
  }, {
    "_id": 824,
    "target": 27,
    "source": 28
  }],
  "levels": [0, -1, -2, 1, -3]
}
```